# Error: Virtualbox unable to insert the virtual optocal disk C:\ Program Files \ Oracle \ Virtualbox \ VBoxguestadditions.iso into the machine Xubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, copy-and-paste

I am a beginner and just installed VM VirtualBox 6.1.16140961-Win and xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.
As I was not able to copy / paste from my pc (Windows 10) with Ctrl+Alt+C / Ctrl+Alt+V (and even Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V,  I was going to install and enalble Guest Addition with

`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms`

but simply nothing happens!
If I do Devices/Insert Guest Addition CD Image I get this error:

Virtualbox unable to insert the virtual optocal disk C:\ Program Files \ Oracle \ Virtualbox \ VBoxguestadditions.iso into the machine Xubuntu

Can someone help to solve this problem please? I already powered off the VM, I already rebooted it but nothing.
In the Storage/Optical Drive I have VBoxGuestAdditions.iso even if I did not select it...no clue

Also in Devices/Optical Drivers the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is checkmarked...

Comment: Is there not by coincidence another image in your virtual optical disc?  If it is, there will be a checkmark next to it.

Comment: No, it is not. If I select Devices/Optical Drivers then VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is checkmared. Is this what you mean? Also if I go in Settings/Storage I find under Controller IDE: VBoxGuestAdditions.iso. I am completely stuck..

Comment: After I removed the GuestAddition CD and did the 'sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms' again it worked. But still the same error. When you say  "What is the output of ls /bin/uname? Is directory /bin in your path? " how can I check it if it is still relevant? thankssss

Comment: Virtualbox unable to insert the virtual optocal disk C:\ Program Files \ Oracle \ Virtualbox \ VBoxguestadditions.iso into the machine Xubuntu ...this error I mean – Marzia

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  Does the same happen with another .iso file e.g. your xubuntu installation iso?  Did you install without problems from an .iso file?

Comment: Yes the installation of xubuntu from the iso file was ok

Comment: The installation of xubuntu seemed to be ok. But if I go in Xubuntu Optical Disk Selector there are 2 iso files. One of them has a yellow ! and if i go on it it says "could not open the medium 'C:\Users\myname\Downloads\xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64 (1).iso'       VD:error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file ´C:\Users\myname\Downloads\xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64 (1).iso' (VERR_FILE_NOT FOUND). Could the error be related to this?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms`
has to be done in a terminal IN THE VM.
The current GuestAdditions.iso contains a set of commands that needs these installed.

If the ISO is already mounted (ticked in the settings), it cannot be inserted, giving the error you have.

Also if the ISO is present DURING BOOT, it will not Autostart.
Remove and Reinsert it using Virtualbox settings  or menus - alternatively start a Terminal/Shell and launch the "autostart" script from there, it is present on the virtual disk created by the ISO.

Comment: When I do in the Terminal of the VM 'sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms' it says "uname -r command not found". I also did Remove and Reinsert it using Virtualbox settings by doing Force Unmount and then I selected it again. I tried again to do Devices/Insert GuesAddition CD Image but keep getting the same error! pffff kinda desperated. Not sure I understood your "start a Terminal/Shell and launch the "autostart" script from there, it is present on the virtual disk created by the ISO''. can you guide me in that? Thanks a lotttt

Comment: I removed the GuestAddicion CD and did the 'sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms' again. now it said: building dependency tree...done / dkms is already the ndewest version (2.8.1-5ubuntul). build-essential is already the newest version (5.4.0-62.70). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Then I reinseret the Guest AdditionCD again from Settings/Storage/Optical Drive/select/VBoxGuestAddition.iso and I tried again Devices/Insert Guaest addition....but I keep getting the SAME ERROR1 kinda desperate!

Comment: Virtualbox unable to insert the virtual optocal disk C:\ Program Files \ Oracle \ Virtualbox \ VBoxguestadditions.iso into the machine Xubuntu ...this error I mean – Marzia

Comment: Now I tried to do all the steps from the beginning removing first in Settings/Storage any CD and I succeeded...! Thank you! I don't know what I did different before, probably something stupid but now it worked....sorry I am just a beginner. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe the automatic mount of the disk did not happen when the disk was 'inserted', for some reason.   I adapted the answer.  And you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the GuestAddition CD is present in your optical disk (checkmarked) and the command
`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms`
has succeeded then execute the next commands
`cd /media`
`cd <your_user_name>`
`cd VBox_Ga*`
`./autorun.sh`
If the disk is not mounted, you can try to do it manually.
`ls /dev/sr*`
This will typically show /dev/sr0.  Then:
`sudo mkdir /media/<your_user_name>/ANameToChooseForTheDisk`
`sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/<your_user_name>/ANameToChooseForTheDisk`
If the mount succeeds (read-only) the contents of the disk show up in ANameToChooseForTheDisk and you can run the ./autorun.sh from there.

Comment: I tried it but the command cd VBox_Ga* does not seem to work as it says ''no such file or directory''. The Guest Addition CD is present in the optical disk (checkmarked) and also iI can see it in Settings/Storage in the Optical Drive ...I have a screenshot but don't know how to attach it here..

Comment: Now I tried to do all the steps from the beginning removing first in Settings/Storage any CD and I succeded...! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open your Ubuntu machine, click *Files* on the left side of the screen and then click on the pop-up *Other locations* at the bottom, and on the new pop-up click *Ubuntu*, then click the media folder which opens up to a folder bearing your username. Click it which opens to a VBox_Gas file.
Right-click the file and select *Open in termina*l which opens a terminal.

In the terminal type `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` and press Enter.